# Find the value of the determinant $\scriptsize \begin{vmatrix} 8-x & -10 & 6 \\ 8 & -9-x & -1 \\ 16 & -15 & 9-x \end{vmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need to determine the value of the determinant and have it represented as product of factors.

\begin{vmatrix}
 8-x & -10 & 6 \\ 
 8 & -9-x & -1 \\ 
 16 & -15 & 9-x
\end{vmatrix}

Also I need to use the properties of determinants since using Sarrus' or Laplace's Rule right away won't do me much good in a sense that I would obtain a polynomial of a degree higher than 2 that needs to be factored, and I want to (and I need to) avoid that.

So far I've rewritten it as:

\begin{vmatrix}
 8-x & -10  &  6\\ 
 0 & \frac{8+x+x^2}{8-x} & \frac{-56+x}{8-x} \\ 
 0 & \frac{40+15x}{8-x} & \frac{-24-17x+x^2}{8-x} 
\end{vmatrix}

But when I multiply the 2nd row by $\frac{-(40+15x)}{8+x+x^2}$ and add it to 3rd row I do obtain a triangular determinant (value of which is obtained by multiplying the elements on the main diagonal) but it's still in the form of an unfactored polynomial. That requires then further polynomial factorisation which I'm not allowed. I need to have it factored right from the determinant.

Any smarter way to do so maybe? Other than this algorithmic Gauss approach (rewriting the determinant to its equivalent triangular form).

Comment: There is no way to avoid the fact that the determinant of this matrix is a cubic polynomial.  Why do you say you're not allowed to factor a cubic?

Comment: It is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix that has entries the numbers without $x$.  See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=charactristic+polynomial{{8,-10,6},{8,-9,-1},{16,-15,9}}

Comment: If you use Sarrus, and simplify, you get a fairly simple cubic polynomial.  The leading coefficient is $1$ and the constant term is $256$.  The rational root theorem says that rational roots must divide $256$, so plug in some powers of $2$ and you'll soon have your factorization.

Comment: The thing is ... I need to find eigenvalues... and it's way easier to find it when you obtain factored form right off the bat. I can have a polynomial of degree 3 and higher but I am clumsy at solving them, especially when I have limited time to do so.

Comment: And it often happens that a zero of a cubic polynomial isn't an integer... so what then?

Comment: Can't you use computational-algebra tools like @EmilioNovati did? When yes then why?

Comment: @Tobias Could you use any computational-algebra tools on your exams? If yes then why?

Comment: @tyr: B. Goddard's solution is the way to go. Otherwise, just use [Cardano's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients).

Comment: I think it's $-(x-16)(x+4)^2$ . :-) Method: Put in $4$ different values and build up the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is possible at all - at least not in a general setting. In the process of triangulization you will almost surely always get non-factorized polynomials on the main diagonal (like in your example) which will eventually lead you to a non-factorized characteristic polynomial.

Just imagine there would be a way, by simple gauss-elimination, to achieve an upper triangle matrix with factorized main diagonal. This would essentially mean, we would have found a way to factorized cubic polynomials (not by using Cardano's formula). I am not an expert in complexity nor in information theory, but it seems very unlikely that this could work.

Instead I would recommend to use either

- [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)
- [or the Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (as mentioned in the comments already), after using [Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) to calculate the determinant

While Cardano's formula works in the general case, we would have to calculate a lot and errors are likely. If we are dealing with an integer matrix (at least in this case) we can apply the rational root theorem safely (like in your example) since we'll always have
$$
 \phi(x)=\pm x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{0}
$$
with $a_i\in \mathbb Z$. So we can just test all the divisors of $a_0$ to find the roots of your polynomial (or find one and then jump to polynomial division). So in your example we really just have to test the divisors of ($\pm$ is relevant)
$$
a_0=256 \text{ which are } 1,2,\ldots,2^8
$$
which gives eventually the factors $x_{1,2}=-4$ and $x_3=16$ and finally
$$
\phi(x)=-(x - 16) (x + 4)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is a cubic.  It is $-x^3+8x^2+112x+256$  The rational root theorem says the roots, if rational, are positive or negative factors of $256$, which doesn't give too many to try.  For class problems, the roots of polynomials higher than quadratics are usually integers, so those are the things to try.  This one factors as $-(x-16)(x+4)^2$